# Lagrangian contradicting itself? Need help

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I've been practicing for exams today and one of the problems involved finding max of a surface given another surface as restriction.

$f(x, y, z) = x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2:$ The surface

$g(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4:$ The restriction.

The problem is that in class we learned that the Lagrangian is 
$L(x,y,z,\lambda)=f(x,y,z)+\lambda g(x,y,z).$

But also the theory is that $\nabla f(x,y,z) = \lambda\nabla g(x,y,z).$ How can this be true? If I move the right side to the left I get $\nabla f(x,y,z) - \lambda\nabla g(x,y,z),$ but the Lagrangian is given as $f(x,y,z)+\lambda g(x,y,z).$ I know the former uses gradients but to my knowledge partial differentiation doesn't change positive to negative. Please help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of notation, and probably you're studying from two different sources. Some authors prefer to write the Lagrangian as

$$
L({\bf x}) = f({\bf x}) \color{red}{-}\lambda g({\bf x}) \tag{1a}
$$

which leads to

$$
\nabla_{\bf x} f({\bf x}) = \color{red}{+}\lambda g({\bf x}) \tag{2a}
$$

While other authors write

$$
L({\bf x}) = f({\bf x}) \color{orange}{+}\lambda g({\bf x}) \tag{1b}
$$

resulting in

$$
\nabla_{\bf x} f({\bf x}) = \color{orange}{-}\lambda g({\bf x}) \tag{2b}
$$

You just need to be aware of the convention the author is using and make sure you keep it until the end

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you very much.